# Deny accessing apache if server's ip address is in URI (no domain name)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, webmin

I would like to deny access (from outside) to http / https ports when the server's ip address is used in the URI and there is no domain name. Is this possible?

The server is Ubuntu 20.04 and uses Linux IPTables Firewall + Webmin.

Comment: Are you using Apache, NGINX or other webserver or you want to do it to Webmin?

Comment: I am using Apache. It is for Apache web server, not webmin.

Comment: I believe you can use name-based Apache's VirtualHost. So this virtualHost only will "answer" to you domain or IP that you configure.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html